# swfupload - get image dimensions

Tags: javascript, swfupload

First of all congrats to everyone for a great job.

swfupload is a very good and quality tool.

My question would be, is there any method in the script to check the dimensions of the image and if the dimensions are not correct display warning popup and not save the image.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all congrats to everyone for a great job.

Why, thank you! I'm also rather pleased with the progress I've made today. ;)

> is there any method in the script to check the dimensions of the image

I'm pretty sure this can be done by tweaking SWFUpload's source but I don't know whether that function is available in "native" form. What SWFUpload can do in its new 2.5 version, though, is [resize images](http://demo.swfupload.org/v250beta3/resizedemo/index.php) on the client side. I gather it is possible to set fixed dimensions for that. Maybe that works for you?

Comment: I would need to alert dimensions of the image when I select the picture for upload

Comment: @Wizard sorry, I don't know whether that is possible out of the box. It certainly is if you know Flash. Maybe this is best to ask on the SWFUpload forums.